# Java 8 Stream , convert List<File> to Map<Integer, List<FIle>>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have below code in traditional java loop. Would like to use Java 8 Stream instead. 
I have a sorted list of files(Sorted by file size). I group these files together in a way that the total size of all files does not exceed the given max size and put them in a Map with the key 1,2,3,... so on. Here is the code.

```
    List<File> allFilesSortedBySize = getListOfFiles();
    Map<Integer, List<File>> filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<File>>();
    double totalLength = 0L;
    int count = 0;
    List<File> filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = Lists.newArrayList();
    //group the files to be zipped together as per maximum allowable size in a map       
    for (File file : allFilesSortedBySize) {
        long sizeInBytes = file.length();
        double sizeInMb = (double)sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
        totalLength = totalLength + sizeInMb;
        if(totalLength <= maxSize) {
            filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize.add(file);
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
            filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.put(count, filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize);
            filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = Lists.newArrayList();
            filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize.add(file);
            totalLength = sizeInMb;
        }
    }
    filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.put(count+1, filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize);
    return filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap;
```

Comment: Is the creation of new ArrayLists in `else` a bug or an extra feature?

Comment: Once filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize is added in the Map, I want to create a new ArrayList for next iteration.

Comment: @NewQueries I have fixed my answer,you can see that I was right?I'm not good english, so if I was wrong,please tell me.

Comment: @NewQueries Hi,after a few minutes I found the grouping method have a bug,I have fixed it,and give the all tests to you,I wish it could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after reading,I found the solution using `Collectors.groupBy` instead.

### Code using java8 lambda expression

```
private final long MB = 1024 * 1024;

private Map<Integer, List<File>> grouping(List<File> files, long maxSize) {
    AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicLong groupSize = new AtomicLong();
    return files.stream().collect(groupingBy((file) -> {
        if (groupSize.addAndGet(file.length()) <= maxSize * MB) {
            return group.get() == 0 ? group.incrementAndGet() : group.get();
        }
        groupSize.set(file.length());
        return group.incrementAndGet();
    }));
}
```

### Code provided by @Holger then you are free to checking group whether equals 0

```
private static final long MB = 1024 * 1024;


private Map<Integer, List<File>> grouping(List<File> files, long maxSize) {
    AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(0);
    //force initializing group starts with 1 even if the first file is empty.
    AtomicLong groupSize = new AtomicLong(maxSize * MB + 1);

    return files.stream().collect(groupingBy((file) -> {
        if (groupSize.addAndGet(file.length()) <= maxSize * MB) {
            return group.get();
        }
        groupSize.set(file.length());
        return group.incrementAndGet();
    }));
}
```

### Code using anonymous class

inspired by @Holger, All “solutions” using a grouping function that modifies external state are hacks abusing the API,so you can use anonymous class to manage the grouping logic state in class.

```
private static final long MB = 1024 * 1024;

private Map<Integer, List<File>> grouping(List<File> files, long maxSize) {
    return files.stream().collect(groupingBy(groupSize(maxSize)));
}

private Function<File, Integer> groupSize(final long maxSize) {
    long maxBytesSize = maxSize * MB;
    return new Function<File, Integer>() {
        private int group;
        private long groupSize = maxBytesSize + 1;

        @Override
        public Integer apply(File file) {
            return hasRemainingFor(file) ? current(file) : next(file);
        }

        private boolean hasRemainingFor(File file) {
            return (groupSize += file.length()) <= maxBytesSize;
        }

        private int next(File file) {
            groupSize = file.length();
            return ++group;
        }

        private int current(File file) {
            return group;
        }
    };
}
```

### Test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

/**
 * Created by holi on 3/24/17.
 */
public class StreamGroupingTest {


    private final File FILE_1MB = file(1);
    private final File FILE_2MB = file(2);
    private final File FILE_3MB = file(3);

    @Test
    void eachFileInIndividualGroupIfEachFileSizeGreaterThanMaxSize() {
        Map<Integer, List<File>> groups = grouping(asList(FILE_2MB, FILE_3MB), 1);

        assertThat(groups.size(), equalTo(2));
        assertThat(groups.get(1), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_2MB)));
        assertThat(groups.get(2), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_3MB)));
    }


    @Test
    void allFilesInAGroupIfTotalSizeOfFilesLessThanOrEqualMaxSize() {
        Map<Integer, List<File>> groups = grouping(asList(FILE_2MB, FILE_3MB), 5);

        assertThat(groups.size(), equalTo(1));
        assertThat(groups.get(1), equalTo(asList(FILE_2MB, FILE_3MB)));
    }

    @Test
    void allNeighboringFilesInAGroupThatTotalOfTheirSizeLessThanOrEqualMaxSize() {
        Map<Integer, List<File>> groups = grouping(asList(FILE_1MB, FILE_2MB, FILE_3MB), 3);

        assertThat(groups.size(), equalTo(2));
        assertThat(groups.get(1), equalTo(asList(FILE_1MB, FILE_2MB)));
        assertThat(groups.get(2), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_3MB)));
    }

    @Test
    void eachFileInIndividualGroupIfTheFirstFileAndTotalOfEachNeighboringFilesSizeGreaterThanMaxSize() {
        Map<Integer, List<File>> groups = grouping(asList(FILE_2MB, FILE_1MB, FILE_3MB), 2);

        assertThat(groups.size(), equalTo(3));
        assertThat(groups.get(1), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_2MB)));
        assertThat(groups.get(2), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_1MB)));
        assertThat(groups.get(3), equalTo(singletonList(FILE_3MB)));
    }

    @Test
    void theFirstEmptyFileInGroup1() throws Throwable {
        File emptyFile = file(0);

        Map<Integer, List<File>> groups = grouping(singletonList(emptyFile), 2);

        assertThat(groups.get(1), equalTo(singletonList(emptyFile)));
    }

    private static final long MB = 1024 * 1024;

    private Map<Integer, List<File>> grouping(List<File> files, long maxSize) {
        AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicLong groupSize = new AtomicLong(maxSize * MB + 1);

        return files.stream().collect(groupingBy((file) -> {
            if (groupSize.addAndGet(file.length()) <= maxSize * MB) {
                return group.get();
            }
            groupSize.set(file.length());
            return group.incrementAndGet();
        }));
    }

    private Function<File, Integer> groupSize(final long maxSize) {
        long maxBytesSize = maxSize * MB;
        return new Function<File, Integer>() {
            private int group;
            private long groupSize = maxBytesSize + 1;

            @Override
            public Integer apply(File file) {
                return hasRemainingFor(file) ? current(file) : next(file);
            }

            private boolean hasRemainingFor(File file) {
                return (groupSize += file.length()) <= maxBytesSize;
            }

            private int next(File file) {
                groupSize = file.length();
                return ++group;
            }

            private int current(File file) {
                return group;
            }
        };
    }


    private File file(int sizeOfMB) {
        return new File(String.format("%dMB file", sizeOfMB)) {

            @Override
            public long length() {
                return sizeOfMB * MB;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                File that = (File) obj;
                return length() == that.length();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to use groupSize.set(file.length()) instead of set(0) and also new AtomicInteger(1)  for my usage. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @NewQueries I'm sorry,I'm a little tired,because I'm at where at 3:00AM.so there still having a bug.I fixed it,but I can tell you,you can't initialized with AtomicInteger(1) that I having tested,are you copy mine tests and test your solution,that can't passed.because if the first file size large than maxSize the first group starts at `2` not `1`.

Comment: You can do it like in my loop variant, initialize `groupSize` with `maxSize` (in bytes), so that the first file will always create a new group. So you can keep `group`’s initial value zero, but don’t need a conditional in `current(File)` (likewise, no test for zero is needed in the lambda variant).

Comment: @Holger thanks very much,nice solution.I will update my answer with your loop variant.

Comment: @Holger there still having a little problem if the first file is an empty file.I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the processing of each element highly depends on the previous’ processing, this task is not suitable for streams. You still can achieve it using a custom collector, but the implementation would be much more complicated than the loop solution.

In other words, there is no improvement when you rewrite this as a stream operation. Stay with the loop.

However, there are still some things you can improve.

```
List<File> allFilesSortedBySize = getListOfFiles();
// get maxSize in bytes ONCE, instead of converting EACH size to MiB
long maxSizeBytes = (long)(maxSize * 1024 * 1024);
// use "diamond operator"
Map<Integer, List<File>> filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap = new HashMap<>();
// start with "create new list" condition to avoid code duplication
long totalLength = maxSizeBytes;
// count is obsolete, the map maintains a size

// the initial "totalLength = maxSizeBytes" forces creating a new list within the loop
List<File> filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = null;

for(File file: allFilesSortedBySize) {
    long length = file.length();
    if(maxSizeBytes-totalLength <= length) {
        filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = new ArrayList<>(); // no utility method needed

        // store each list immediately, so no action after the loop needed
        filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.put(filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.size()+1,
                                     filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize);
        totalLength = 0;
    }
    totalLength += length;
    filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize.add(file);
}
return filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap;
```

You may further replace

```
filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = new ArrayList<>();
filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.put(filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.size()+1,
                             filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize);
```

with

```
filesWithSizeTotalMaxSize = filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.computeIfAbsent(
        filesGroupedByMaxSizeMap.size()+1, x -> new ArrayList<>());
```

but there might be different opinions whether this is an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. But I was wondering if groupingBy can be used.

Comment: Not really. All “solutions” using a grouping function that modifies external state are hacks abusing the API, relying on the way the stream will process the collector in a sequential context (needless to say that they will break badly in a parallel context). Likewise, they will break when you try to combine this collector with other collectors. And they are horribly inefficient, compared to the straight-forward loop.

Comment: @Holger Hi,"All “solutions” using a grouping function that modifies external state are hacks abusing the API" but you can use an anonymous class to manage its own state instead.

Comment: @Holger and his problem can't use in a parallel context,that will results different groups.even if you use loop to group files with maxSize,because file must be grouped in order.

Comment: @Holger sir,what I said is right?I want to learn more,if I'm wrong,please tell me,thanks.

Comment: @holi-java: since loops never run in parallel, you are not tempted to switch them to parallel. That’s different to Streams, which can be turned to parallel with a single method call. As said, these `groupingBy` will also break in sequential context, when being composed with other collectors. E.g., `groupingBy(someFunc, groupingBy(anotherFunc))`. If `anotherFunc` is the function of your answer, the solution will break (as soon as the outer operation finds more than one group).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to the problem I could think of is to use an `AtomicLong` wrapper for the size and a `AtomicInteger` wrapper for length. These have some useful methods for performing basic arithmetic operations on them which are very useful in this particular case.

```
List<File> files = getListOfFiles();
AtomicLong length = new AtomicLong();
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);
long maxLength = SOME_ARBITRARY_NUMBER;
Map<Integer, List<File>> collect = files.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        file -> {
            if (length.addAndGet(file.length()) <= maxLength) {
                return index.get();
            }
            length.set(file.length());
            return index.incrementAndGet();
        }
));
return collect;
```

Basically what `Collectors.groupingBy` does the work which you Intended.